# Javascript Div rollovers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Jquery - is there a simple way to change the background color on a div when a user rolls over it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with CSS:

```
#myDiv:hover { background-color: red; }
//or...
div:hover { background-color: red; }
```

If you need IE6 support and such and *have* to use jQuery, toggle a class, like this:

```
.hover { background-color: red; }
```

Then use [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/), like this:

```
$(".myDivs").hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

Comment: Is using a psuedo classes on a div valid?

Comment: Definitely the time and place to use CSS. :)

Comment: @Thomas - Yes, only older IE(6) has an issue, everyone else supports it IIRC. IE6 only supported the `:hover` pseudoclass on anchors.

Comment: @Thomas - There's nothing wrong with that (I checked... it passed CSS validation).

Comment: @Thomas - If it's important to support IE6, then you can add the hover effect with jQuery (see Darin Dimitrov's answer).

Comment: @Gert - I've included this already...far better to do this with a class, much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event:

```
$('#divid').hover(function() {
    // mouse enter
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
}, function() {
    // mouse leave
    $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `mouseenter` & `mouseleave` is better than hover. Why? Bubbling reason ;)

```
if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7) {
    $('element').bind({
        mouseenter:function(){ $(this).addClass('over'); }, 
        mouseleave:function(){ $(this).removeClass('over');}
    });
}
```

After this, you can simply add some CSS magic:

```
#element.over,
#element:hover {
/* do something */
}
```

Comment: .support is preferable rather than browser sniffing http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/